# Busy-body curves have to be long

Tags: real-analysis, curves

**Question:**

Prove that for every positive constant $C$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that any curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ whose image has points at distance $\leq \epsilon$ from each point of the unit square $[0,1]^{2}$ must have length $\geq C$.

**My problem:**

I have difficulty in understanding the question

- <strike>how can a point in the image of a curve have a distance $\leq \epsilon$ from all the points of the unit solid square? I assume that $\epsilon$ can be chosen as a small value.</strike>
- Also, suppose the length of one curve is $C^{\prime}$, and we can find an $\epsilon$, then this $\epsilon$ holds for all $C > C^{\prime}$ for this particular curve. How could this curve have length $\geq C$? (this is also related to understanding "any" curve, that is, for any curve, we have a $C$, or for any $C$ we have all curves satisfying blablabla).

Any explanation to help me understand this problem? Thank you!

**Edit:**

Thank you @Robert Israel for making my first bullet clear. However, I am still puzzling about my second bullet. I re-state my second bullet as follows,

Prove that, given any curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, for every positive constant $C$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every point from the unit square $[0,1]^{2}$ we can always find at least one point from the image of this curve at distance $\leq \epsilon$, then this curve must have length $\geq C$.

Does my statement have the same meaning as the problem does? If so, what does the $C$ do in the statement? It seems only the $\epsilon$ is related to the curve.

Regarding the example below. The curve has a length of 4.75, and we find an $\epsilon = 1/8$ to satisfy all the requirements, but since $C$ is irrelated to the $\epsilon$, I can claim the statement holds for arbitrary $C >0$, so the length of this curve should be arbitrarily large. A contradiction. Now I was wondering if there must be some places where I misunderstood the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For example, the red curve has distance $\le 1/8$ from all points of the unit square.

[image]

- Suppose for example you were to claim that $\epsilon = 1/8$ works for $C = 2$. Since my red curve works for $\epsilon = 1/8$, it would imply that my red curve has length $\ge 2$.  Well, my red curve has length  $4.75$, and that's greater than $2$, so no problem.  If you were to find some other curve with length $< 2$ that is within distance $1/8$ of every point of the square, **that** would contradict your claim.  But if there is no such curve with length $< 2$, your claim is true.

Comment: oh, so for my first bullet, you mean that the image contains points such that some points in the image have distances of less than $\epsilon$ from some point of the unit square instead of from all the points of the unit square, right?

Comment: For each point $p$ of the unit square, there is a point $q$ of the curve at distance $\le \epsilon$.

Comment: Prof. Israel, May you have time to take a look at my new edit, which is related to your example. Thank you

Comment: The question does **not** say "given any curve in $\mathbb R^2$".  It says that given any $C$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that **every** curve that works for that $\epsilon$ has length $\ge C$.  Or to put it another way, if a curve has length $< C$, there is some point in the square that is at distance $> \epsilon$ from the curve.

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask the following, Is $\epsilon$ a function of $C$ just like the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language is? I think in this problem, it is not, that is one of my puzzles.

Comment: Yes, $\epsilon$ depends on $C$.  That's exactly what the question says: " for every positive constant $C$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that ...

Comment: It seems that your red curve is a counterexample, so the question is wrong

Comment: @hmeng What do you think it is a counterexample to, and why?

Comment: Because for any positive $C$, we can find $\epsilon = 1/8$ such that the red line has points at distance $\leq \epsilon$ from each point of the unit square, but the length of the red curve is $4.75$, if we choose $C > 4.75$, a contradiction. Right?

Comment: @hmeng The existence of the red curve shows that for $C > 4.75$, $\epsilon$ must be $ < 1/8$.  The question just says for each $C$ there is some $\epsilon$. As long as you don't claim $\epsilon \ge 1/8$ when $C  > 4.75$, there is no contradiction.

Comment: but there is no restriction that I cannot take $\epsilon \geq 1/8$ for any $C$? Now I know where I am stuck, that is, I may misunderstood the range of the quantifiers

Comment: The question is, how to show that for any $C$ there is some $\epsilon$ that works?

Comment: Thank you! Now it is clear